# Executing a js function only once per visit and execute again on refresh

Tags: javascript

I want the following code to run only once per visit. If i navigate from homepage to different page and come back to homepage, i should not see the effect again. If i refresh the page, i should see the effect. Here is the code :

```
function stack(){
       $('#image').animate({
            width: 200,
            height: 150,
            top: 0,

        },1500);
}
$(function(){
    stack();
});
```

Here is what i am doing : http://jsfiddle.net/kq5M4/

Comment: Try using cookies with JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: how to delete cookies on refresh ?

Comment: is the different page a page part loaded from AJAX or is it a whole new page load?

Comment: it's a whole new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a cookie that marks that the effect has occurred, but also set a cookie on each page load that keeps track of the last page. If when the home page loads and the last visited page was also the home page, run the effect again.

(Using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.)

On the home page:

```
var lastPage = $.cookie('last_page');
if (!lastPage || lastPage == document.location.pathname)
    stack();
```

On every page (including home page):

```
$.cookie('last_page', document.location.pathname, {expires: 0}); // expires: 0 makes it a session-only cookie
```

You may *also* need to check the referrer so it will run again if they leave your site and come back later.

Answer (score 1):

on page load, check `document.referrer` and if is different from your domain or blank, then do the animation. navigating between your pages or refreshing the page will have your domain in `document.referrer` so you'll skip the animation.

```
$(function(){
    if (!document.referrer.match(/buybluesky.com/) || document.referrer == document.location.href) {
      stack();
    }
});
```

Edits:
It seems i missed something but I've reedited the code to match all your criterias. Beside checking for the referer to decide if it needs to show or not the animation, it also checks if referrer is equal to the current location. If they are that means it was a refresh since you came to this page from this page.

Comment: I think OP *does* want the effect to happen again on refresh, in which case this won't quite do it.

Comment: fixed now. it checks if referrer is = to current location. if so, then it must be a refresh

Comment: `document.referrer` is the same before and after a refresh, so this won't work either.

Comment: true. i did some browsing and somehow for the flow i tested it worked just fine.

Comment: I tried this here but what i want is after animation it should be in it's normal state (shrinked)

http://jsfiddle.net/kq5M4/

Answer (score 1):

Use sessionStorage & store the last page:

```
var visited = sessionStorage.getItem('visit');

if (visited == null || document.location.href == sessionStorage.getItem('lastPage')) {
    stack();
    sessionStorage.setItem('visit', 1);
}

sessionStorage.setItem('lastPage', document.location.href);
```

Comment: but what happens if you navigate away or close the browser and come back in a month ? that value will still be there and there will be no animation.

Comment: @TheBrain `sessionStorage` isn't very persistent. It only lasts as long as the browser is open. This is even better than cookies I think.

Comment: @KingKongFrog, what if they come from another page after visiting this one? `visit` will be 1, but `document.location.href` will equal `lastPage`, unless you add `sessionStorage.setItem('lastPage', document.location.href);` in other pages. You should specify it in your answer.